# Invalid expression "else"

Tags: c#, if-statement

I just got into programming , tried everything but the first else is always invalid, its probs real obvious but cant figure it out

```
if (answer == (num1 * num2)) 
{
    int responsegen = numbergenerator.Next (1, 4);

    switch (responsegen)  
    {

        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine ("Congrats! You're a natrual");
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine ("Correct, Mini Einstein maybe?");

        default :
            Console.WriteLine ("Right answer , are you cheating?");

} 
else // this one right here 
{
    int diff = (answer - (num1 * num2));

    if (diff == 1) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("OHH so close you were only of by one number!");
    }

    if (diff <=10) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Incorrect but you were close, only of by " + diff + "better luck next time!");                  
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not close your switch block after default.

Comment: With the code styling you had you will never know where the problem actually is. Some people including me have fixed the code styling. Now check if it is actually your code. Make changes if I occasionally changed your code. Your question sounds like your code was compiling but this one shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do this:

```
switch (responsegen)  {
    //...
} else
//...
```

You can't follow a `switch` statement with an `else`.  `switch` uses the `default` clause within its list of cases as a logical "else". (Which you're using already, so what you're doing doesn't even semantically make sense.)

Maybe you meant to attach the `else` to the preceding `if` block?:

```
if (answer == (num1 * num2)) {
    //...
    switch (responsegen)  {
        //...
    } // <-- first close the switch block
} else // <-- then continue the if block
//...
```

As you continue learning about programming, you'll find that using consistent and clean use of whitespace (carriage returns, indentation, etc.) makes things like this *a lot* easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a brace, and a couple of `break;` statements:

```
if (answer == (num1 * num2)) 
{
    int responsegen = numbergenerator.Next(1, 4);

    switch (responsegen)  
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Congrats! You're a natural");
            break;

        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Correct, Mini Einstein maybe?");
            break; // <-- you need a break; here...

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Right answer, are you cheating?");
            break; // <-- ...and here.
    } // <-- add a brace here
} 
else
{
    int diff = answer - (num1 * num2);

    if (diff == 1) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OHH so close, you were only off by one number!");
    }
    else if (diff <= 10) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect but you were close - only off by " + diff + ". Better luck next time!");                  
    }
}
```

I've corrected your spelling and grammar as well, as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You re missing 2 break statements and a curly brace.

Working code:

```
        if (answer == (num1*num2))
        {
            int responsegen = numbergenerator.Next(1, 4);

            switch (responsegen)
            {

                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Congrats! You're a natrual");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Correct, Mini Einstein maybe?");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Right answer , are you cheating?");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else // this mofo right here help!!!! 
        {
            int diff = (answer - (num1*num2));

            if (diff == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OHH so close you were only of by one number!");
            }

            if (diff <= 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect but you were close, only of by " + diff + "better luck next time!");
            }
        }
```

Also, even once it compiles, the if statement is a bit suspect ... if 'diff' is 1 then you'll get two messages written to the console ...